# displaying user entered text on same PyQt4 Window

Tags: python, pyqt4

I am trying to display user entered text in edit text on the same window, I see that you can display the text on QMessageBox as it asks for the parameters to display here is the code for displaying on Qmessagebox how do I display it on the PyQt window.

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *


class AppForm(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.create_main_frame()

    def create_main_frame(self):
        page = QWidget()

        self.button = QPushButton('joy', page)
        self.edit1 = QLineEdit()
        self.edit2 = QLineEdit()

        vbox1 = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox1.addWidget(self.edit1)
        vbox1.addWidget(self.edit2)
        vbox1.addWidget(self.button)
        page.setLayout(vbox1)
        self.setCentralWidget(page)

        self.connect(self.button, SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.clicked)

    def clicked(self):
        QMessageBox.about(self, "My message box", "Text1 = %s, Text2 = %s" % (
            self.edit1.text(), self.edit2.text()))




if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = AppForm()
    form.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Your question is unclear, you could explain me better please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use TextEdit to accomplish what you are trying to do, it can be set to readonly as well.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton('button')
        self.textedit = QtGui.QTextEdit()
        self.textedit.setReadOnly(True)
        layout.addWidget(self.textedit)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.testing)

    def testing(self):
        self.textedit.append('hello world')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Window()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```